# Visual Studio git: "Commit and Push" and "Commit and Sync" options missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

I'm using VS2022 and I have a C# project that only has a "Commit" option in the solution explorer git tab. The options "Commit and Push" and "Commit and Sync" are missing. Interestingly, I have a second project which has same setup (C#, git, github), and in that project all three options are available (please see screenshots). Go figure. Does anyone know how I can get the Commit and push option back ? Thanks

[options are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd77F.png)

[options available in aother project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6gu2.png)

Comment: Do you have a remote origin set up?

Comment: yes, I use github, and everything seems to be working fine. It is a company internal github server at a large company. Since my older project has the options I thought this can not be part of the problem (?)

Comment: with remote origin, you mean a github remote ? That is setup and working. I am new to git and github. I would say that whatever I did, it was the same for the two projects.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem. The remote link name was the project name instead of origin. I changed it to origin and the two additional options are showing up. Strange this is that the other project that has all 3 options also had as url link name the project name (no origin). Anyways, question has been answered. Thanks to @Hans Kesting for the hint. This whole topic was new to me and I found the solution by watching YouTube and googling for remote origin.